# Return Array from Firebase snapshot method

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm connecting to `Firebase` and retrieving data from a given location, what I'm trying to do is loop through the `snapshot.val()` build and `Array`, return the `Array` and then loop through it on the `component.html` and build a `Dropdown`.

At present I'm having difficulty figuring out the syntax for such service method, this is my current code. - This is called from `app.component.ts` within `ngOnInit()`

```
getExerciseOptions(): Array<Exercise> {

    const items: Exercise[] = [];

    this.exerciseDbRef2.on("value", (snapshot) => {

        snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
            items.push({
                id: snap.key,
                description: snap.val().description
            });
            return false;

        });
    });
}
```

So `this.exerciseDbRef2` points to the table within `Firebase` as shown here:

```
private exerciseDbRef2 = this.fire.database.ref('/exercise_description');
```

The error I'm currently receiving is

```
A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
```

Which I understand, so when I change `return false` to `return items` the new error is:

```
Argument of type '(snap: DataSnapshot) => Exercise[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: DataSnapshot) => boolean'.
Type 'Exercise[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

I have looked at using `child_added` but from my understanding this will be called every time a new child has been added into that location, which is not what I'm looking for.  The children in this location will not change nor will any be added. - Maybe I've misinterpreted 'child_added' ?

I'm rather new to `Firebase` so I'm at the beginning on the learning curve so please bare with, I would also like to mention if the way I'm currently doing this is not correct then please bring it to my attention.

So for clarification : Connect to `Firebase`, retrieve all children from given location i.e exercise_description table, loop through the `snapshot`, build an `Array` and return it.

Then on the component loop through the `Array` and build the `Dropdown`.

Can someone please explain how I go about returning the `Array` based off the `snapshot.val()` ?

Comment: That snippet does not look complete. Have you chopped bits out? The error implies that the `on` callback is returning an array. And the `getExerciseOptions` function is declared as returning `Array<Exercise>`, but returns nothing.

Comment: @cartant thanks for helping in advance, the snippet it correct.  I'm confused in regards to the syntax on how I go about returning the array built with the values returned from `Firebase`. Ideally I want to return `Array<Exercise>` from this function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return an array from `getExerciseOptions`, as the `value` event is asynchronous.

However, you could return a promise:

```
getExerciseOptions(): Promise<Array<Exercise>> {
    return this.exerciseDbRef2
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        const exercises: Exercise[] = [];
        snapshot.forEach(snap => {
            exercises.push({
                id: snap.key,
                description: snap.val().description
            });
            return false;
        });
        return exercises;
    });
}
```

You would then call it like this:

```
getExerciseOptions().then(exercises => console.log(exercises));
```

If you are unfamiliar with promises, you might want to read [*JavaScript Promises: an Introduction*](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises).

Comment: Thanks so much for the example, will try this shortly.  Question though I have a few tables within `Firebase` which I'll be making calls to and again returning the data and building several `Dropdowns` based off the children in these tables on my `component.html` page, what you have provided would that be suitable from a performance aspect? or could I use an observable here? - Just trying to get a better understanding, hence the stupid question o_O

Comment: Any performance difference depends upon how you've structured things. The advantage that observables have is that they can continue to emit values - so they can be hooked up to the `child_added/removed` events, etc. which could involve less data transfer and repeated, promise-based queries. I see that you are using Angular, so you might want to check out [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) to see what's possible with observables and Firebase.

Comment: Ok sounds good, I'll take a look an AngularFire2 also, just tried the getExerciseOptions method you provided and I'm getting the following error: Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Exercise[]>'.
  Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type 'Promise<any>'.

Comment: It's just the Firebase TypeScript definitions. The promise declared for `once` does not use generics. You'll have to cast it: `return this.exerciseDbRef2.once("value").then(...) as Promise<Array<Exercise>>;`